# たとえ-Continuative-たとしても

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, copula, ambiguity

> 「そう、この世界には死者は存在しない。
>   夢というものは生者が見る共通無意識だ。
>   故に、すでに死亡したものはこの場に参加する事ができない。
>   **たとえおまえ自身が強く記録し、その復活を望んだ人間がいたとしてもだ。**
>   些細な役回り……そうだな、通行人Ａという役割を用意したとしても、死者はこの劇場に入れない。
>   役割があっても役者がいないという事だ」
>
> In this world there are no dead people.
>   A dream is a shared subconscious the living see.
>    Therefore, dead people cannot be invited into this world.
>    Even though you yourself strongly recorded it and even if there was a person who wishes for revival.
>   A trivial role, yes.
>   Even if you prepared the role of passerby A, the dead cannot come on this stage.
>   Even if there is a role there is no actor.

Can someone help me with that bold part?

Also I do not understand

> その復活を望んだ人間がいた
>   A: The person who desired for revival
>   B: The person whose revival you desired

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> たとえ{おまえ自身が(強く記録し、その復活を望んだ)→}人間がいたとしてもだ。

たとえ～としてもだ means "(the aforementioned sentence is true) Even if ...". たとえ is optional. Example:

> 何も喋るな。たとえ聞かれてもだ。  (≒ たとえ聞かれても、何も喋るな。)
>   Don't say anything. Even if you're asked.

その復活を望んだ人間がいた refers to B: the person whose revival you desired. Depending on the context, 復活を望む人間 by itself can mean "someone who is dead and desires their own revival", "someone who desires someone else's revival" or "someone whose revival someone else desires". In your case, the implicit change of subject is unlikely to happen after te-from (記録し), so it's 'おまえ自身' who desired something. And of course, a dead person can't have desire in this situation (because they don't exist!).

---

By the way, that そうだな is not "yes" but like "say" used to give an example.

> Even if you prepared some trivial role, say, the role of passerby A, ...

Comment: What about the first part: たとえおまえ自身が強く記録し= Even if you registered. It does not make much sense to me tough, Does that have any other meaning?

Comment: Doesn't make quite sense to me, either :-)  I just assumed maybe this conversation was done between Grim Reapers, who might "record" deaths. Or maybe was this a typo for 記憶し (memorize)?

Comment: Oh ok, the thing is that he keeps on repeating the same day and when it ends he forgets what happened but he cannot record anything since even if he wrote them down they would disappear, in this context I thing 記憶し would have been a better choice.