# how to know the usage of として

Tags: grammar

Hi I was wondering how として was used in this sentence. I already know it can be used as: `as, even, apart from`, but I'm having trouble figuring out the differences in some sentences .

> たとえ　君が 痛みに慣れているのだとしてもだ

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29797/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58702/9831

Answer (score 2):

> たとえ　君が 痛みに慣れているのだとしてもだ

Here it means something like "even supposing". "Even supposing you are used to pain ..."

Sounds like something from some comic or something.